# How to access table from Hive cluster located in HDInsight from Local Spark Server built on Intellij

Tags: azure, apache-spark, hive, azure-hdinsight

I am not able to access and read data from Hive table located in HDInsight from my local Instance where application build on Intellij and Maven.

May someone please help me what are the Pre-requisite for scenario when we need to write data from Spark to Hive , but Hive is located on HDInsight and Spark is on local native instance.

Note: I don't have Spark cluster on HDInsight , i only have hive cluster on HDInsight.

Please share your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add the hive-site.xml of the cluster in your resources folder. Also, make sure you have the network port open for the local network. Please refer the below link.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark%3A+Getting+Started

Comment: Thanks, do i also need to configure in POM file ?

Comment: you need to have spark-hive_2.11 dependency if not added.

Comment: Please help: where will i get Hive-site.xml in HDInsight ?

Comment: you can download the config from Ambari UI in HDInsight.